# Get the json data from a collection filled with objects

Tags: php, json, laravel, object, collections

Laravel
I have a problem finding a data inside a collection which is filled with objects.
My collection is look like this:

```
return collect([
        new Aligator('1', 'name1'),
        new Aligator('2', 'name2'),
        new Aligator('3', 'name3')];
```

The data which I want to search is the name, given through url with contoller.

```
Route::get('/aligator/{name}', [AligatorController::class, 'getAligator'];
```

After clicking the link the user wants to see his aligator as Json data. Not formatted at all.

I tried a lot of things but unluckey.

Thank for the help.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses

Comment: No problem. Google and the documentation is your friend...